# WiFi scan limits on LineageOS and LineageOS for microG

Tags: wi-fi, lineageos

Starting with Android Pie, wifi scans are [heavily throttled](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-throttling): the limit is up to four times every 2 minutes for a foreground app, and once every 30 minutes for all background apps combined. This has massive impact on apps that rely on WiFi for geolocation, mapping or other purposes (see e.g. [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112688545)).

Does anyone happen to know if LineageOS (and its derivative LineageOS for microG) introduce any changes that relax these limits? (Especially since microG comes with location providers which utilize wifi.) Or do they simply copy that behavior?

Comment: Note that the used method for Wifi scanning [WifiManager.startScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startScan()) has been marked deprecated. It will be removed in a future Android version. This means that may be starting with Android 10 (or 11) Wifi scanning is longer available to apps.

Comment: I’m aware of that, also of the discussion surrounding it. Is there any other way for an app to find out which wifi networks are available nearby, with a frequency in the range of a few seconds? (How does Google solve it for their own network location service?) Though I realize that is probably a separate question…

Comment: According to an XDA article the next Android version (Q) will allow to disable throtteling via adb command: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-throttling-wi-fi-scans-crippling-apps/

Comment: Yep, I saw that already. However, according to Google (and unlike what is stated in the article), this requires a rooted device (source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129900566#comment11). It may not work for others, but at least LineageOS provides a root add-on, thus any LineageOS user should be able to relax these limits. Still this is a setting which needs to be made per device.